# Create New User in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

I already installed Oracle Database 11.2 release. and ODC for visual studio also.

After all I try to create user in SQL Developer but its always saying `Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`

I want to know what is the issue with this and how i solve this

Comment: The answer is in the exception message, you are logging in with the wrong credentials.

Comment: @ThanosMarkou In the installation i gave myDB for connectin Alias after oracle to Database Host Name and port is 1521 Database Service Name orcl so what is the user name from these names ?

Comment: When you specify username and password for a connection in SQL Developer, that does **not** "create" user. You have to supply an existing account. If you don't have one, you need to ask your DBA to create one

Answer (score 0):

Probably either your user has no permissions to connect or you forgot the password of your user. If so

1. connect as admin to your database
2. type `alter user <YOUR_USER_HERE> identified by 123`
3. try to connect with password 123.

If you can't connect then either your listener is down or your database is unavailable.

- Use the command line tool lsnrctl to find out if your listener is assigned with your database.
- User SQL*Plus to mount your database. Execute: `startup force`

PS: Have you tried to google your problem? I got [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hUuZDm2Kjts) after 5 seconds I began the search.

Comment: ah no what i got after all saying lack of privileges. but i solved it by granting the resource to user thank you for help